# AH01630: client denied by server configuration in Django

Tags: django, linux, apache2

My website is working but it is not displaying static files present in my project folder. I am getting this error

`AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /home/ubuntu/project/static/js/homepage.js, referer: http://test.com/home/`

Here is the configuration for static in my .conf file:

```
Alias /static /home/ubuntu/project/static
<Directory /home/ubuntu/project/static>
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

I have followed answers online and added Require all granted but still no luck.

My other sites are up and running using same configuration. But this one is causing the error. Any ideas?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have resolved the issue. If anyone else facing it may try this solution.

I was serving the site in my `/home/ubuntu`. I use this for my other websites and they work fine. But in this case I was getting the error. So I moved my site to `/var/www/html` and now its working.